# Python socket not connecting on LAN

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I'am a beginner in sockets and networking in general and i am trying to test it out on my LAN. However every time i try to connect to the server nothing happens until it throws an error saying: "Connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection 
 failed because connected host has failed to respond". The code that i am using is found here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication. I have changed the ip to my ipv4 address but nothing else.

Comment: Probably you have a firewall that's blocking the server.

Comment: Check whether the firewall on the server allows connections to port 5000 from your client machine.

Comment: I have already tried making inbound and outbound rules on both machines but it still didn't work. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: What port number are you using?

Comment: I am using port 5005